# How is the Mann Whitney U test statistic derived?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

The t-test statistic is derived from the CLT and allows for some probabilistic statements to be made.

$$ U_1 = n_1(n_1+1)/2 + n_1 n_2 - R_1 .$$

I know the test does not assume a probability distribution; though, I was wondering where this formula came from, why it is defined in this way and how we are able to make probability statements about the similarity of two groups from it.

Comment: The corresponding [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#History) links to the early papers on this statistic by Wilcoxon, Mann, Whitney, and Deuchler. You might find answers there. Mathematically, the wiki also explains that you are indirectly summing up a piecewise function indicating the inequality.

Comment: What matters for a test is not the law that generates the data: it is the distribution of the *test statistic.*  Assuming only that the data-generation process is a continuous distribution, under the null hypothesis $U_1$ has a distribution that depends only on $n_1$ and $n_2.$  This is what makes such tests effective.  It works this way because $U_1$ depends only on the order of the data, not on their values; and the assumption of continuity assures that all $(n_1+n_2)!$ possible permutations of the data are equally likely.

Answer (score 4):

A general outline is worth to delve into:

The Mann-Whitney U statistic can be defined (cf. $\rm [I]$) as the number of times $Y$ exceeds $X$ in the combined ordered arrangement of independent samples $\langle X_i\rangle_{i=1}^m, ~\langle Y_j\rangle_{j=1}^n.$ Succinctly

$$U:= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n\boldsymbol 1_{X_i< Y_j}\tag 1\label 1.$$

Consider now the Wilcoxon sum statistic

$$W:= \sum_{j=1}^n R(Y_j),\tag 2\label 2$$

where $R(Y_j)$ is the rank of $Y_j$ in the combined sample. How are $\eqref 1, ~\eqref 2$ related (cf. $\rm [II]$)?

For that, notice

$$R(Y_j) = \sum_{i=1}^m \boldsymbol 1_{X_i< Y_j} + \sum_{k=1}^n\boldsymbol 1_{Y_k< Y_j}+1;\tag 3\label 3$$ substituting $\eqref 3$ in $\eqref 2$ yields

\begin{align}W &= \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^m\boldsymbol 1_{X_i< Y_j}\right) + \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n\boldsymbol 1_{Y_k< Y_j}+n\right)\\&= U +\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\tag 4\label 4.
\end{align}

So, from $\eqref 4,$ the Mann-Whitney U statistic can be equivalently expressed as $$U = W-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.\tag 5\label 5$$

---

In adherence to the notations used by OP, consider the two samples of sizes $n_1, ~n_2$ and the sum of the corresponding ranks of the observations in the respective samples be denoted by $R_1, ~R_2.$ Also, let $N:= n_1+n_2.$

Naturally,

$$R_1 + R_2 = \frac{N(N+1)}2. $$ That is,

\begin{align}R_1+R_2&= \frac{(n_1+n_2)(n_1+n_2+1)}2\\ &= \frac{n_1^2+ n_1n_2+n_1 + n_2n_1+ n_2^2 +n_2}{2}\\&= \frac{n_1(n_1+1)}{2} + n_1n_2 + \frac{n_2(n_2+1)}{2}\tag{6.a}\label{a}; \end{align}

from $\eqref a,$

$$R_1 - \frac{n_1(n_1+1)}{2} =n_1n_2 + \frac{n_2(n_2+1)}{2} - R_2;\tag{6.b}\label b  $$

in $\eqref b,$ LHS is of the form $\eqref 5;$ hence

$$U_2 = n_1n_2 + \frac{n_2(n_2+1)}{2} - R_2.$$

Similarly,

$$U_1 = n_1n_2 + \frac{n_1(n_1+1)}{2} - R_1.$$ Interestingly, it follows $U_1 + U_2 = n_1n_2.$

---

### References:

$\rm[I]$ Nonparametric Statistical Inference, *Jean Dean Gibbons, Subhabrata Chakraborti,* Marcel Dekker, $2003,$ sec. $6.6,$ p. $268.$

$\rm [II]$ Nonparametric Statistical Methods, *Myles Hollander, Douglas A. Wolfe, Eric Chicken,*  John Wiley & Sons, $2014,$ sec. $4.1,$ pp. $126-127.$

$\rm [III]$ Biostatistical Analysis, *Jerrold H. Zar,* Pearson Education, $2014,$ p. $171.$

Comment: Thanks for this, this is a great answer! I just had one follow up question: why isn't U_2 dependent on R_1 and vice versa?